# Importing data from Outlook to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently developing a macro/add-in for Excel, to import e-mails from Outlook.

When I tested with an e-mail that fit all the conditions set by me, it worked just fine.

However, when I tested with more than one e-mail, I got a 'Subscript out of range' error.

I've read my code left to right and right to left but I can't find out what I did wrong.

Here's the code I have so far (I'm sorry for the messy code, I'll clean it up after everything is running smoothly).

```
Sub GetDataFromOutlook()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer
'Dim LR As Long
Dim dbf As Worksheet
Dim ar() As String
ReDim ar(0 To i)

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set dbf = Sheets("DBF")
'LR = dbf.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
i = 0

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
ar() = Split(OutlookMail.Body, ",")
    If InStr(OutlookMail.Subject, "Exportation of purchase order") > 0 Then
        For Each Item In ar
            Range("batch_reference").Offset(i, 0).Value = Left(ar(i), WorksheetFunction.Find("-", ar(i), 1) - 1)
            Range("batch_reference").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
            i = i + 1
        Next Item
    End If
Next OutlookMail

    Columns("A:A").Select
    dbf.Range("$A$1:$A$100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    dbf.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    dbf.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DBF").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:A100")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

The highlighted line with the error is "Range("batch_reference").Offset(i, 0).Value = Left(ar(i), WorksheetFunction.Find("-", ar(i), 1) - 1)"

Any insight on what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your `ar` array, it will be an array of `0..n` **each time**.  So, although `i` will point to the desired array element of the first mail item, when you process the second mail item, `ar` again is a `0` based array, but `i` is pointing to the next row on the worksheet, which will be much greater than `0`.

Suggest something like:

```
 Range("batch_reference").Offset(i, 0).Value = Left(Item, WorksheetFunction.Find("-", Item, 1) - 1)
```

Or, perhaps:

```
Range("batch_reference").Offset(i, 0).Value = Split(Item, "-")(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your suggestion worked like a charm.
Just one more thing (I hope you can help me with it as well.), every e-mail starts with "Please find enclosed coding informations for following sample(s) :", which means that the first ID in the e-mail body won't be properly imported to Excel. Is there a way or a piece of code that I can use to get everything past the ":" character?

Comment: @Barbaaz If there are no other colons to worry about, something like `Split(Split(str(I), ":")(0), "-")(0)`.  If your pattern variations are more complex, you can probably use regular expressions instead, or just restrict using the colon to the first pass through with each email.

Comment: I know this is going to sound dumb, but I am not sure where to add that bit of code.

Comment: @Barbaaz In place of the `Split` statement you would be using in your code, had you followed my second suggestion.

Comment: I followed your second suggestion, but I'm still missing the first ID from the e-mail body. I'm not sure if the fact that there's a line break after the "Please find enclosed coding informations for following sample(s) :" has anything to do with it. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Barbaaz Not enough information to figure out your problem.  But it's just string manipulation similar to your first attempt.  Or narrow things down to just splitting the different types of lines, and post that alone as a new question with examples, attempted code, desired output, and clear problem statement.

Comment: I'm sorry for being vague. As you might understand, I can't post the full content of the e-mail for confidentiality reasons.
I'll try to replicate something similar.
"Please find enclosed coding informations for following sample(s) :
0021225331-001, 0034654869-003, 0003112023-012, ...
0021225331-001, 0034654869-003, 0003112023-012, ..."
If I can "start" spliting the string in the second line, I'm sure I can fix this issue.
The desired output should be the IDs without the "-", separated in rows.

Comment: @Barbaaz Comments are not good for this process. Please post your splitting problem as a new question, following the guidelines I noted above.

Comment: Will do!
Once again, thank you very much for your help. :)